# Función en javascript para transformar centena a hora

Tags: javascript

Tengo un inconveniente al mostrar una hora de mi registro ya que yo manejo las horas por identificadores donde `600 es 6:00` , `630 es 6:30`, `1400 es 14:00`, etc.: en pocas palabras, se elimina el ":".

En lo que solicito su colaboración es en lo siguiente:

```
$horas_reservadas = "1100 - 1230 - 1300";
```

yo quiero poner esto: `toHour($horas_reservadas);`

y el resultado que sea: `11:00 am - 12:30 am - 01:00 pm` ya que 14:00 es la 01 de la tarde.

Mi solución (errónea) es:

```
let $array_horas= [600=>"6:00 am",630=>"6:30 am",...,1400=>"01:00 pm"];
```

y luego recorrer cada ítem y reemplazarlo por su valor, pero sé que esto tiene una mejor solución.

Contexto:
Yo desde mi php mediante `$.post` recibo este string: `1900 — 1930 — 1700 — 1730 — 1800 — 1830` pero a mi cliente deseo mostrarlo en horas formateadas.

Answer (score 0):

El objeto `Date()` tiene los métodos `setHours()` y `setMinutes()` a partir de eso luego puedes mostrar una hora en un formato específico usando `toLocaleString()` para el formato 12 horas `hour12: true`. El hecho de que el formato pueda tener 1 o 2 dígitos para la hora (01:00 o 6:00) hace que tengamos que usar `splice()` o algo similar para tomar la hora contando 2 desde el final.

```js
const horas = "1900 — 1930 — 1700 — 1730 — 1800 — 1830";

const res = horas.split(" — ").map(e=>{

let d = new Date();

let h = e.split("");

let min = +h.splice(-2,2).join("");
let hor = +h.join("");

d.setHours(hor);
d.setMinutes(min);

return d.toLocaleString('es-ES', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, minute: 'numeric' });

});

console.log(res);
```